# How to limit number of post archives in category on home page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been searching for many hours for this solution and can't figure out an answer.

On my home page, I have a section displaying recent posts where it shows permalink titles, and excerpts. It's  showing all of the published posts in this specific category but I need to limit the number of posts to 3.

I've tried everything but nothing is working.
My index file points to a loop-index.php file so that's where I've been editing code although I've tried changing code in the index.php file as well as the loop-index.php and the functions.php file

Here's a link to the code:
https://gist.github.com/rwilki/3ab9192955891f43ac01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add before While loop This Argument.

```
query_posts('post_type=post&posts_per_page=2&orderby=menu_order&order=DESC');

while (have_posts()) : the_post(); unset($prev); $m++;

Set YOur lImit posts_per_page=2  //change your value
```

Comment: worked great! thanks so much! I had to add this because I needed to restrict it to a specific category
`&cat=17`
You're awesome Ravi...